# Read ERA5 netcdf as raster in R with correct extent (lat/lon)

Tags: raster, r, netcdf

I'm attempting to read a netCDF file from ERA5 using the `raster` package in `R`. **An example file is downloadable [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An3uxwv5VwUIicVC4CuP33Wgk72RzA?e=sAsaNV).**

As ERA5 detail [here](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CKB/ERA5%3A+What+is+the+spatial+reference),

> global ERA5 data was interpolated to a regular lat/lon grid with resolution r = 0.25 deg. The 'top left' ERA5 data point is always at Longitude=0 ; Latitude=90, with further grid points spaced by r, and the 'bottom right' grid point at Longitude=360-r ; Latitude=-90.
> Many software applications by default visualise regularly spaced data as a continuous tiled surface, as in (b). If you use this visualisation, think of coordinates as referencing the centroids of the tiles.

So essentially, ERA5 data is created like this:
[image]

But the `raster` package in R reads a 0.25° data file as this:

```r
library(raster)
stack(sample_ERA5.nc)
```

[image]

And therefore gives me this output:

```r
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 721, 1440, 1038240, 249  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : -0.125, 359.875, -90.125, 90.125  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

Note the wrong extent and the 721 rows, where there should only be 720. Of course I could `resample()` it to the right extent and resolution, but this distorts data, which is not what I want to do!

Any ideas on how to create an R raster of this data? Perhaps via loading them as points and then rasterizing it? I definitely want to keep the data in it's "original form".

Comment: 721 seems correct, its the length of the sequence from -90 to +90 by 0.25.

Comment: not resample, just do `extent(r) <- extent(0, 360, -90, 90)` - might look at exactly *why* this nc gets interpreted this way, but netcdf is a huge ball of fun with infinite possibilities so it's not unsurprising

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems here. The extent as a raster is according to the interpretation in the ERA5 docs, such that the extent overlaps on the left and at the top and bottom, but doesn't reach +360, with the overlaps being all 1/2 the grid size:

```
> era = raster("./sample_ERA5.nc")
> extent(era)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -0.125 
xmax       : 359.875 
ymin       : -90.125 
ymax       : 90.125
```

If you want this as points, then `rasterToPoints` returns the point-based interpretation, with the coordinates being the correct rounded coordinates given in the ERA5 documentation:

```
> head(rasterToPoints(era))
        x  y       tp
[1,] 0.00 90 9.336591
[2,] 0.25 90 9.336591
[3,] 0.50 90 9.336591
[4,] 0.75 90 9.336591
[5,] 1.00 90 9.336591
[6,] 1.25 90 9.336591
```

Comment: Thanks Spacedman! So if I understand this correctly, then to get a raster that resembles `raster(res = 0.25)` , then I'm left only with resampling?

Comment: If you want a raster with extent (0,360) and (-90,90) with 0.25 cells, then (because the definition of "extent" includes the cell sizes) you will have to interpolate 721  to 720 rows and interpolate across half a column width as well to shift the grid over. The docs seem to read that  you should consider the data to have "point support" at the given coordinates, rather than as values over any grid cells.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
cdo -f nc4 -z zip_1 sellonlatbox,-180,180,-90,90 infile.nc outfile.nc
```